# Ordenar los índices de una tabla en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo puedo ordenar el índice (id) de una tabla en MySql?

**Ejemplo:**

indice(id):

> 1, 6, 8, 10 ...

y que quede

> 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Answer (score 2):

Primero ejecuta:

```
SET @i=0;
UPDATE una_tabla SET id=(@i:=@i+1);
```

Después modifica la tabla para que el valor de auto_increment  concuerde con tus nuevos índices.

Comment: Gracias, este método también lo emplearé.

Answer (score 0):

He podido hacer de la siguiente manera:
ALTER TABLE NombreTabla DROP id;
ALTER TABLE NombreTabla AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE NombreTabla ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

Comment: Es diferente a lo que ha dicho @Muriano. Así eliminas la columna id y la vuelves a crear añadiendole las caracteríaticas necesarias (auto_increment, not null y primary key), aunque creo que es "mejor" lo que te ha comentado el compañero, así no corres el peligro de olvidarte alguna propiedad o de que te de fallo.

Comment: Estupenda explicación para tenerla en cuenta. Muchas gracias.